# Oracle Apex multiple level approval workflow

Tags: oracle-apex

I am building the issue tracker application similar to the one in oracle docs.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e11945/issue_track_obj.htm#BABIIBBF

In short a dynamic approval workflow, where multiple approvers can be added or deleted using tree structure.

I am not asking anyone to design this for me, but any help in atleast giving a brief overview of how this can be done or if someone has done it, maybe tips would be very valuable.

Comment: Hi Vini, do you still need help with this or was David's answer sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vini,
From a high level you would need to define a DEPT_APPROVERS Table which lists for each department who the individual approvers are. Then you could send notifications to all of the approvers listed based on which Department is assigned to the person making the request.
Regards,
David

Comment: I have raised a separate question David, where i wish to use triggers for this. Do you mind taking a look here and advise if something can be done? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477214/oracle-apex-multi-approval-implementation-via-trigger-logic?noredirect=1#comment108750742_61477214

Comment: I provided a more detailed answer in your new question.
Please mark this question as answered.